# Is any getPrototypeOf alternative for IE8 ans less?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm using getPrototypeOf method in IE8, but it does not work. How can I fix this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Look for a shim, such as [john resig's](http://ejohn.org/blog/objectgetprototypeof/)

Comment: Better solution: Don't support IE8 and less :)